# How to specify "unique" values in Rails 3, PostgreSQL next to existing "unique key"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have existing Rails app written in Rails 3.2 and using PostgreSQL as db engine. Our products table holds products from several websites. Every product currently gets an unique id upon entry.

Here is the model :

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :url, :country, :email
  validates :name, :presence => true, 
        :length => { :minimum => 1 }
  has_many :sectors
end
```

and database schema for this table from schema.rb

```
create_table "platforms", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at",                               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               :null => false
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "email"
  end
```

Is it possible to add another "unique key" that would forbid entry or new products using the "URL" parameter? I am not sure hot to achieve such a thing with `Rails g migration` without damaging existing records (if duplicates already exist).

So basically : I want rails to forbid addition of a new product if the url of the new product corresponds to the url already in the database, similar as I am not allowed to enter product with id=1 if there is a product with id=1 in the database already.

Comment: I don't understand your request, do you want to have products with unique URL for each?

Comment: I want rails to forbid addition of a new product if the url of the new product corresponds to the url already in the database, similar as I am not allowed to enter product with id=1 if there is a product with id=1 in the database already.

Comment: PostgreSQL will enforce unique constraints on your existing data so you won't be able to add one if you have duplicates already. You'll have to try to enforce your uniqueness using a validation in your Rails code (but that leaves you open to race conditions) or using a trigger (but Rails makes that a nightmare).

Comment: I would recommend you use a database-level constraint as opposed to something in Rails or a trigger because 1) This would require you to clean out duplicates manually before applying the constraint.It seems odd to me to have a constraint for some records but not all, so for good data integrity you should fix existing records first. 2) The database will do a better, faster job of this, so let it.  Plus there are the concerns Mu mentioned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that on the model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :url
end
```

Or (depending on your DB, MySQL could react differently than PGsql):

```
# migration file
t.string :url, :null => false, :unique => true
```

Comment: You won't be able to add a unique constraint if there are duplicates already in the database, PostgreSQL (thankfully) will want the constraint to be true for everything in table. And `validates_uniqueness_of` is subject to race conditions as noted in [the validations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness).